# PHP 5.3 remove get_magic_quotes_runtime()?

Tags: php

I got the below error when I upgraded to PHP 5.3

```
Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated
```

I am planning to remove the code set_magic_quotes_runtime()

I have get_magic_quotes_runtime() also in my code

Can I remove this as well?

Is there any point keeping get_magic_quotes_runtime() in the code?

Comment: Magic quotes still exist in PHP 5.3. If you have them turned off in PHP.INI and are aware of the implications of doing so, you can remove the references in your code. Magic Quotes were removed entirely in PHP 5.4. The question is, why aren't you upgrading to the current version of PHP (v5.6) instead of a version that is already at end-of-life?

Comment: Also note that `get_magic_quotes_runtime` is not the same as `get_magic_quoted_gpc` (which is the more common misconfiguration on dated setups). Without further details and concrete code samples, nobody can give you absolution on having used or continuing to use it.

Comment: There will be a lot of issues if I upgrade to the current version. So I thought of upgrading step by step so that I get less issues in each version and easy to solve it. I don't have much time for upgrade. So if I upgrade to current version, I may have to spent lot of time to fix the issues. If I upgrade step by step, I can finish it in the timeline. I believe it is good to remove get_magic_quotes_runtime as well since it will be deprecated when I upgrade to PHP 5.4